# Where to buy just the plastic cases for dice?

Tags: dice

Where would I buy just the plastic cases that polyhedral dice sets come in?

Comment: Maybe ask your fellow gamers if they have some kicking around. I personally prefer a dice bag(my own build) as some of the players in the campaign I'm in borrow dice(non core players). Also you may want to flesh the question out with why you want the cases.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're not sold retail and you'd have to find a wholesaler who supplies the dice companies, and they probably have some kind of minimum order. Are you looking for a few or a few hundred?

Comment: I've seen Chessex at Gen Con sell them individually for $1.

Comment: It would be better to state your region/country since local shop suggestions would be useless unless we know where you are and most online stores do not ship to everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, this question is basically asking us to do your shopping for you and is not a good fit for our Q&A style here. We try to keep our questions to things centered around game play rather than where to buy stuff.

Answer (score 6):

The Dice Shop are selling these: [25 x Standard Perspex Dice Cubes](http://www.thediceshoponline.com/dice/6336/CLEARANCE-25-x-Standard-Perspex-Dice-Cubes). I expect that some of the other specialist Dice Shops sell them too.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your normal game stores there is a brick & mortar store called the "Container Store" where I saw several differe nt sizes of them. (They weren't referred to as dice containers)

And ofcourse Amazon has them:  [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008CYUXLM)  is one I just found using my phone; I'm sure there are a lot more, its just harder to search Amazon on this phone.